# Display all clients who have booked a room

Tags: php, sql, subquery

Subquery returns more than 1 row and this is the error. I want to print all the `booked room` details showing the `client id` and the `owner id`.

```
$query = "SELECT r.room_id, r.roomsize, r.numberroom, r.price, u.username,
(SELECT u.username FROM room_register r 
INNER JOIN user_info u on r.owner_id = u.user_id  
INNER JOIN booked b on b.room_id = r.room_id)as owner_name 
FROM room_register r INNER JOIN booked b on b.room_id = r.room_id 
INNER JOIN user_info u on u.user_id = b.booked_by";
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your table here

Answer (score 2):

You have too many joins in the subquery:

```
SELECT r.room_id, r.roomsize, r.numberroom, r.price, u.username,
       (SELECT u.username
        FROM user_info u 
        WHERE r.owner_id = u.user_id  
       ) as owner_name 
FROM room_register r INNER JOIN
     booked b 
     ON b.room_id = r.room_id INNER JOIN
     user_info u 
     ON u.user_id = b.booked_by;
```

Or just use two separate `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT r.room_id, r.roomsize, r.numberroom, r.price, u.username,
       uo.username as owner_name 
FROM room_register r INNER JOIN
     booked b 
     ON b.room_id = r.room_id INNER JOIN
     user_info u 
     ON u.user_id = b.booked_by LEFT JOIN
     user_info uo
     ON uo.user_id = r.owner_id
```